# creating a difference file from .csv files

Tags: c#, ms-access, difference

I am creating an application which converts a MS Access table and an Excel sheet to .csv files and then differences the access table with the excel sheet. The .csv files are fine but the resulting difference file has errors in fields that contain html (the access table has fields with the html). I'm not sure if this is a special character issue because the special characters were not an issue in creating the .csv file in the first place, or if it is an issue with the way I am differencing the two files.

Part of the problem I suppose could be that in the access .csv file, the fields that contain the html are formatted so that some of the information is on separate lines instead of all on one line, which could be throwing off the reader, but I don't know how to correct this issue.

This is the code for creating the difference file:

```
    string destination = Form2.destination;
    string path = Path.Combine(destination, "en-US-diff.csv");
    string difFile = path;
    if (File.Exists(difFile))
    {
        File.Delete(difFile);
    }
    using (var wtr = new StreamWriter(difFile))
    {
        // Create the IEnumerable data sources
        string[] access = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(csvOutputFile);
        string[] excel = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(csvOutputFile2);

        // Create the query

        IEnumerable<string> differenceQuery = access.Except(excel);

        // Execute the query
        foreach (string s in differenceQuery)
        {
            wtr.WriteLine(s);
        }        
    }
```

Comment: csv is more suited for tabular data, in this case maybe xml is a better choice, you can use CDATA fields for html code..

Comment: You need a key for the rows.  Then you can create a custom compare and pass it to `Except()`.  I've done it and WOW is it fast.

Comment: Logical lines versus physical lines.  I had this problem before also.  I solved it by placing sentinels at the end of each logical line when the files were first created.  Time was short in that particular effort and I'm sure there is a better way. XML CDATA might be the preferred approach as Oscar pointed out. In the meantime, if you have control when the files are created, consider sentinels.

Comment: @GarryVass Can you expand on sentinels. I'm not quite sure what I am supposed to do but generally what you're saying sounds like my solution. I have to use csv and you're right about it being a issue with logical vs physical lines

Comment: In the context of your question, you are relying upon the Environment's line feed string to mark the end of a line.  It's something like "\r\n". But when the files are created, you could just add a sentinel to the end of the line, I used something like "##!!##".  When you parse the file in your downstream app, break it out on sentinels and NOT on line feeds.  Of course this strategy assumes you have programmatic control when the files are created.

Comment: Yeah I have control over creating the csv files. Ok I'll try this. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user2390773 If you are totally happy, I can enter this as an 'official answer' so that it can be marked and voted upon.  This will avoid the site software carrying it as an unanswered question and elevate your score for marking answers.

Comment: OK so I changed my code to create the csv file in which it adds a sentinel to the actual end of the final field in a row. But referring to the code I posted above, how do I change that to make it recognize what to do with the sentinel?

Comment: You can enter this as an official answer and I'll mark it as the answer and everything but I would still like to continue discussing this with you. Otherwise your answer was very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physical line versus logical line.  One solution is to use a sentinel, which is simply an arbitrary string token selected in such a way so as not to confound the parsing process, for example "##||##".

When the input files are created, add the sentinel to the end of each line...

1,1,1,1,1,1,###||##

Going back to your code, the System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(csvOutputFile); uses the Environment.Newline string as its sentinel.  This means that you need to replace this statement with the following (pseudo code)...

```
    const string sentinel = "##||##";
    string myString = File.ReadAllText("myFileName.csv");
    string[] access = myString.Split(new string[]{sentinel}, 
                               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

At that point you will have the CSV lines in your 'access' array the way you wanted as a collection of 'logical' lines.

To make things further conformant, you would also need to execute this statement on each line of your array...

```
line = line.Replace(Environment.NewLine, String.Empty).Trim();
```

That will remove the culprits and allow you to parse the CSV using the methods you have already developed.  Of course this statement could be combined with the IO statements in a LINQ expression if desired.